# Downloading normal image Vs retina device image (2x)

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, ios, uiimageview, uiimage

When we need to download an image from some URL and show it on two kinds of devices -- Retina (with 2x image) and regular device -- Should we have two different image URLs to handle this?

For the images in the resource bundle we are keeping both xyz.png and xyz@2x.png and its working fine.

For images we are fetching from server do we need to have separate image URLs for both these kind of images and cache them locally with the same naming convention (xyz.png and xyz@2x.png)?

Please throw some light here.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can check if the device has a high-resolution retina display and based on that download a different image. Don't bother for photos and stuff that you'd scale anyway for interface size. 
You can create the scaled version of the downloaded image with

```
UIImage *image = //download...
image=[UIImage imageWithCGImage:[image CGImage] scale:2.0 orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
```

Keep in mind that a scaled 100x100 image will become a 50x50 points image (with 2.0 scale).

Check first if you have a retina display

```
BOOL retina = NO;
if([[UIScreen mainScreen] respondsToSelector:@selector(scale)])
    retina = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale] == 2.0 ? YES : NO;
```

Comment: One question here. if we need to cache this image in the file system then should we save it with xyz@2x.png format? so that when we retrieve it from the file system IOS could recognize it.

Comment: @Abhinav the @2x magic only works with `[UIImage imageNamed:@"foo"];` And this method only works with images that are saved to the bundle. And the bundle is not writable, you can't save your images there. So you don't have an advantage because of this. BUT the user might use your software on an old device, itunes saves everything, and then he buys a device with retina display and restores the backup with all your image data. He would use the normal images on a retina device then. So I would suggest to use the @2x extension anyway, but you have to manage it manually.

Comment: Ok. So based on whether it is a retina device or not we will still need to differentiate in the file name so that they could be read later on with that name as IOS will not be handling this.

Comment: I would suggest to do this. Just write your own method that picks the correct image based on the `[[UIScreen mainScreen] scale]`. You'll need such a method for the file download anyway. Those little details make the difference between average and great apps.

Answer (score 0):

```
CGFloat screenScale = [UIScreen mainScreen].
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:myUrl] scale:screenScale];
```